# make mask border more distinguished in instance segmentation mask

Tags: python, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have the following instance segmentation mask:

[image]

I want to make the borders between cells more distinguished before transforming it into a binary mask.

If I take the image and just binarize it I get the following image:

[image]

Is there a built-in function that addresses this issue, I couldn't find any?
If there isn't what is the best approach to do it?

The Original image in a `.npy` format is at https://filebin.net/eixoprrp0o7opz7k

Comment: Look up Erosion :) f.e. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erosion_(morphology)

Comment: @PatrickArtner I check it out already, but it works nicely when the image is binary. I'm having trouble in the case where each instance has a different value than 1.

Comment: maybe using a (binarized) copy of the original that you then erode and combine back to the original image (multiply) enlarges the gaps. everywhere you multiply by 0 you get 0, all others keep the same as you multiply by 1?

Comment: can you please upload the original image? I assume you want to separate the touching objects? Or are they labeled already, and you just want to draw the contours?

Comment: @Iammuratc I added the original, let me know if there is any problem with it

Comment: Does the original image itself have the numbered x and y axis, or is it without them? It might be easier for us to work with the image without the axes ( if the axes are not part of the original image). And also @Iammuratc's question seems pertinent to understand the end goal here.

Comment: @GaneshTata I added a link to download the image (without the axis).

Answer (score 1):

I love `opencv` library. Here is an approach for drawing the contours.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

img = np.load('test.npy').astype(np.int32) # the method only works with 32bit image
contour_thickness = 1

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(img , contours, -1, 0, contour_thickness)

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

[image: test_output]

Comment: A very elegant solution, it does exactly what I implemented. (probably efficiently)

Answer (score 0):

So I couldn't find a stright-forward way to achieve my goal so I implemented it myself.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter

def fix_patch(patch, val):
    patch_tmp = np.where(patch == val, patch, 0)
    blurred_patch = gaussian_filter(patch_tmp, sigma=0.7)
    patch_tmp = np.where((blurred_patch < int(0.9 * val)) & (blurred_patch > int(0.5 * val)), 0, 1)
    return patch * patch_tmp


def smart_matrix_indexing(r_min, r_max, c_min, c_max, mat):
    row_max, col_max = np.subtract(mat.shape, (1, 1))
    r_min = np.max([r_min - 3, 0])
    r_max = np.min([r_max + 3, row_max])
    c_min = np.max([c_min - 3, 0])
    c_max = np.min([c_max + 3, col_max])
    return r_min, r_max, c_min, c_max


def fix_segmentation_maps(mask):
    unique_values = np.unique(mask)
    unique_values = unique_values[np.where(unique_values > 0)]
    for val in unique_values:
        r, c = np.where(mask == val)
        r_min, r_max, c_min, c_max = smart_matrix_indexing(r.min(), r.max(), c.min(), c.max(), mask)
        patch = mask[r_min:r_max, c_min:c_max]
        mask[r_min:r_max, c_min:c_max] = fix_patch(patch, val)
    return mask

fixed_mask = fix_segmentation_maps(mask)
```

This will output the following image:

[image]

Logic:

1. find the a window per instance element
2. crop it from the image
3. zero out anything that is not the instance
4. smooth using gausian filter
5. keep the boundaries element
6. inverse the values (1 -> 0, 0 ->1). this will zero out only the boundaries we wish to remove
7. multiply it by the patch and reassign it

So it was able to set the boundaries in some descent way.
If there is a better way I would happy to hear anyway.